# Create new process and pass object

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, remoting, memory-mapped-files

I have a batch application that processes a number of inputs to generate some reports. It reads an input text file, generates a list of report definitions, and then calls external code to run each report.

However, the external report generation code contains some sort of memory leak. When running a single report it has no issue, but with multiple the machine will quickly run out of memory. I've tried clearing the report instances and disposing what objects I can, but the only way I've found to clear the memory is to close the process. If I run each report as a separate process, this solves the issue.

So I require my application to create a new process, pass the report definition object and server information, and get that process to generate the report, and then close. Then repeat for the next definition. I have been looking at .Net Remoting using IPCChannel, however I can't figure out how to simply create the process, pass the information (the report definition and server information) and let it run.

Another option could be using memory mapped files. Or potentially using a console application, but that woulds require serializing my object and passing a large amount of text and many arguments, which isn't elegant.

So what option would be best for creating a process, passing a 'report definition' object and server information, and then allowing the process to close before running again?

Comment: Missed that last part of your question.  What I would do is not do separate processes and instead do separate application domains.  Build a class library to do your reporting stuff and load it in the application domain of a console application.  Then you can pass interfaces back and forth over the app domain.  For each new report, unload the app domain and reload the app domain.

Comment: Optionally just redo your batch file to be a powershell script, and open a new instance of powershell each time you run the script.  Use a parent script to launch a child script in new powershell instances.  Which can be configured to run hidden as a scheduled task.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. This is a .net command line application, and I can launch other command line applications with it. However I need to pass an unserializable object from one to the other - this is the difficulty. I could create a new app domain (I'm about to try that now), but I think the issue of passing an unserializable object will still be there.

Comment: Why don't you just do everything in one process... Then make another process to restart it?  Even keep the definitions in the process being started.  Why does it need to be in Process A.  You could make Process A just a restarter and have the Target process exit with a specific return code.  If Return Code == 0, success done, if not run it again.  In other words you could use the exit code as a loop indicator.  When it's 0 it has no more to do, when it's not it's ready to restart and run the next one.

Comment: If you could post the code making this "non serializable object" it would be easier to come up with a solution.  I don't understand how something written in C# could be non serializable.

Comment: It was unserializable because it was a class from another library - I had no control over it. I have since found a solution - I made a new model that was serializeable, passed over all the information I needed, and then re-built the original object. A bit of a work-around, but works well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using Named Pipes or Anonymous Pipes. These are specifically for inter process communication and they are very fast. See one example using Anonymous Pipes here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx